# How do you handle backwards/forwards .Net framework compatibility (and software distribution)?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, compatibility

Let's say I have created a console application (for simplicity's sake, there are no complicated dependencies on versions of GUI or web frameworks) using .Net 4.5. Next year, ".Net 5" is released and I want to update my application to use the fancy new APIs (to improve performance, source code readability, etc). However, I still want to maintain (critical bug fixes, etc) the previous version of the application for users who haven't upgraded their runtime.

How is this situation handled? Do I need to make 2 executables available and ask that users download the one that is appropriate, or is there a way to distribute a single executable/installer that determines which version to run automatically?

Or, is this even a valid question? If I want to continue supporting users on the "old" .Net 4.5 am I obligated to continue building ONLY against that framework?

Comment: Side note: it may be better to ask that question when you actually know what features you want to use... At least clarification whether you are looking for C# language features, true code .Net assembly changes or NuGet updates.

Comment: Agreed, and maybe I will ask again at that time. I asked it this way for now because I wanted more of a general answer to the problem as a whole, not just a specific solution to my issue at hand. In fact, I am asking the question for a project that I have not started - I just want to start out on the right foot. I don't really know what features I am going to want to use in the future (obviously).

Comment: If you really want to get rid of that trouble, use .NET Core and bundle the runtime with your app at deployment. Then your end users won't have to even install .NET Framework and worry about compatibilities. However, the burden becomes yours, and you have to frequently update your app deployment, as .NET Core runtime upgrades often with security fixes. More can be learned from http://dot.net

Answer (score 0):

Many installers like [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) may provide a way to [implement custom actions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx) so you can detect what is the latest framework version installed in target system and decide what executable to deploy there. [Check this Wix Toolset article about .NET Framework version detection](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html).

In the other hand, you'll need to maintain a source code branch per target framework version if you want to use newer features not available in previous framework versions and merge changes, and make them compatible.

If the features used around your code are very limited, [you can still use preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)  like `#if NETFX_45` or any compilation symbol you can add to your projects, and compile to one or other framework version based on preprocessor conditionals.

Anyway, your final solution will be a combination of handling code versioning the right way and creating custom installer actions to detect user's target system.